# Free statistical textbooks

Tags: teaching, references

Are there any free statistical textbooks available?

Comment: Look at Statistics Topics ebook on Amazon by Mehta, and his free web log Statistics Ideas that has lecture slides. Nearly free and better in some pedagogical topics, than the ones you cite on your list of resources.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Online books include

- http://davidmlane.com/hyperstat/
- http://vassarstats.net/textbook/
- https://dwstockburger.com/Multibook/mbk.htm
- https://web.archive.org/web/20180122061046/http://bookboon.com/en/statistics-ebooks
- http://www.freebookcentre.net/SpecialCat/Free-Statistics-Books-Download.html

Update: I can now add my own forecasting textbook

- [Forecasting: principles and practice (Hyndman & Athanasopoulos, 2012)](https://otexts.com/fpp3/)

Answer (score 63):

The Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman is a standard text for statistics and data mining, and is now free:

https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/

Also Available [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387848576).

Comment: Why pay $70 for the book?  To support the authors and to have a physical copy.  That's why I did it, anyway!

Comment: I agree with Shane... and a hardcopy makes reading it much easier.

Comment: Did that, too (previous edition). But it is nice to be able to look things up online when the book is not at hand. And to have access to the new edition.

Comment: (+1) Just wanted to comment that this is a GREAT book, it is my all-time favorite. I also ordered a physical copy of it :-).

Comment: If you attend Hastie and Tibshirani's Statistical Learning and Data Mining seminar, you'll receive a free copy of the text. And you can have your book signed!

Comment: I have a second edition. It is the best printed book I have - four color printing throughout, excellent typography, great paper.

Comment: Would it be possible to point to the solutions of Elements of Statistical Learning ? Thanks!

Comment: Found it answered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108449/most-efficient-way-to-check-answers-to-exercises-when-learning-from-a-statistics

Answer (score 28):

[Introduction to Statistical Thought](http://www.math.umass.edu/~lavine/Book/book.html)

Comment: Michael Lavine is a clear lecturer and thinker, so I have little doubt his book is worth a look.

Comment: I'm teaching out that book this semester.  It may be a good *statistics* book, but I'm having second thoughts regarding its light probability content.

Answer (score 24):

There's a superb Probability book here:
[https://web.archive.org/web/20100102085337/http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/book.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20100102085337/http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Echance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/book.html)
which you can also buy in hardcopy.;

Answer (score 20):

I've often found the Engineering Statistics Handbook useful. It can be found [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/).

Although I've never read it myself, I hear [Introduction to Probability and Statistics Using R](https://rdrr.io/cran/IPSUR/f/inst/doc/IPSUR.pdf) is very good. It's a full ~400 page ebook (also available as an actual book). As a bonus, it also teaches you R, which of course you want to learn anyways.

Comment: +1 For this resource. As the name says, excellent for a practical approach to engineering problems.

Answer (score 18):

### Machine Learning

- One the most, if not *the* most, popular textbooks on machine learning is  Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman, *[The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Etibs/ElemStatLearn/)*, which is fully available online (currently 10th printing). It is comparable in scope e.g. to Bishop's *Pattern Recognition and ML* or Murphy's *ML*, but those books are not free, while *ESL* is.
- Hastie & Tibshirani also co-wrote freely available *[An Introduction to Statistical Learning, With Applications in R](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/%7Egareth/ISL/)* which is basically a simpler version of *The Elements* and focuses on R.
- In 2015, Hastie & Tibshirani co-authored a new textbook *[Statistical Learning with Sparsity: The Lasso and Generalizations](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/StatLearnSparsity)*, also available online. This one is quite a bit shorter and focuses specifically on lasso.
- Another freely available all-encompassing machine learning textbook is David Barber's *[Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.barber/brml)*. I did not use it myself, but it is widely considered to be an excellent book.

$\hskip{5em}$[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Switching now to more specialized topics, there are:

- Rasmussen & Williams *[Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/)*, which is *the* book on Gaussian processes.
- Much awaited Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville *[Deep Learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/)* textbook that is about to be published by MIT Press. It isn't published yet, but the book is already available online. On the official website one can view it in browser but cannot download (as per agreement with the publisher), but it is easy to find a combined PDF e.g. [here on github](https://github.com/HFTrader/DeepLearningBook).
- Csaba Szepesvári, [Algorithms for Reinforcement Learning](http://www.ualberta.ca/%7Eszepesva/RLBook.html), a concise book on RL. A classical, much more detailed but a bit dated textbook is Sutton & Barto, *[Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Esutton/book/the-book.html)* which is also freely available online but only in a cumbersome HTML format.
- Boyd and Vandenberghe, [Convex Optimization](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/).

$\hskip{4em}$[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 17):

I really like  [The Little Handbook of Statistical Practice](https://web.archive.org/web/20100731030727/http://www.tufts.edu/%7Egdallal/LHSP.HTM) by Gerard E. Dallal

Answer (score 16):

Here's a fresh one: [Introduction to Probability and Statistics Using R](https://rdrr.io/cran/IPSUR/f/inst/doc/IPSUR.pdf) . It's R-specific, though, but it's a great one. I haven't read it yet, but it seems fine so far...

Comment: Link is broken.  Try http://www.lulu.com/items/volume_68/8123000/8123594/3/print/IPSUR.pdf

Comment: First edition at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IPSUR/vignettes/IPSUR.pdf and second edition at http://ipsur.org/

Comment: I downvoted because of "it's a great one.  I haven't read it...."

Answer (score 14):

[A New View of Statistics](http://www.sportsci.org/resource/stats/) by Will G. Hopkins is great! It is designed to help you understand how to understand the results of statistical analyses, not how to prove statistical theorems.

Answer (score 14):

Norman Matloff has written a mathematical statistics [textbook](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/probstatbook) for computer science students that's free.  Kind of a niche market, I suppose.  For what it's worth, I haven't read it, but Matloff has a Ph.D. in mathematical statistics, works for a computer science department, and wrote a really good R book, that I recommend for people who want to go to the next stage of programming R better (as opposed to just fitting models with canned functions).

Answer (score 14):

OpenIntro Statistics

http://www.openintro.org/stat/textbook.php

Inexpensive paperback copies are also available on Amazon.

Comment: I moved this from answer to comment since I am expressing my opinion about free books on the net rather than providing a a list of some. As both an author and owner of books I see both sides. I appreciate that most statistics books, especially when they deal with specialized topics are very expensive. However as an author who has put in a lot of effort to try to write useful and informative books I think the authors and publishers deserve remuneration for the efforts they go through to produce the books. So I don't think books should be free.

Comment: But if authors want to put out material on the internet for free that is their choice. We all can benefit from that.

Comment: You could make the same arguments about software, but we all benefit from R.

Answer (score 13):

"**An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R**" https://www.statlearning.com/ by two of the 3 authors of the well-known "**The Elements of Statistical Learning**" plus 2 other authors.  An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R is written at a more introductory level with less mathematical background required than The Elements of Statistical Learning, makes use of R (unlike The Elements of Statistical Learning), and was first published in 2013, some years after this thread was started.

Answer (score 12):

Not Statistics specific, but a good resource is:  http://www.reddit.com/r/mathbooks
Also, George Cain at Georgia Tech maintains a list of freely available maths texts that includes some statistical texts.  http://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/textbooks/onlinebooks.html

Answer (score 11):

I really like these two books by Daniel McFadden of Berkeley:

- Lecture Notes: Econometric Tools
  http://elsa.berkeley.edu/users/mcfadden/e240a_sp98/e240a.html
- Lecture Notes: Econometrics/Statistics  http://elsa.berkeley.edu/users/mcfadden/e240b_f01/e240b.html

Answer (score 11):

For getting into stochastic processes and SDEs, Tom Kurtz's [lecture notes](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~kurtz/m735.htm) are hard to beat.  It starts with a decent review of probability and some convergence results, and then dives right into continuous time stochastic processes in fairly clear, comprehensible language.  In general it's one of the best books on the topic -- free or otherwise -- I've found.

Answer (score 9):

Cosma Shalizi, CMUs ML guru, occasionally updates a draft of a stats book soon to be published by Cambridge Press titled *[Advanced Data Analysis from an Elementary Point of View](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/ADAfaEPoV/)*. Can't recommend it highly enough...

Here's the Table of contents:

```
I. Regression and Its Generalizations
Regression Basics
The Truth about Linear Regression
Model Evaluation
Smoothing in Regression
Simulation
The Bootstrap
Weighting and Variance
Splines
Additive Models
Testing Regression Specifications
Logistic Regression
Generalized Linear Models and Generalized Additive Models
Classification and Regression Trees 

II. Distributions and Latent Structure
Density Estimation
Relative Distributions and Smooth Tests of Goodness-of-Fit
Principal Components Analysis
Factor Models
Nonlinear Dimensionality Reduction
Mixture Models
Graphical Models 

III. Dependent Data
Time Series
Spatial and Network Data
Simulation-Based Inference 

IV. Causal Inference
Graphical Causal Models
Identifying Causal Effects
Causal Inference from Experiments
Estimating Causal Effects
Discovering Causal Structure 

Appendices
Data-Analysis Problem Sets
Reminders from Linear Algebra
Big O and Little o Notation
Taylor Expansions
Multivariate Distributions
Algebra with Expectations and Variances
Propagation of Error, and Standard Errors for Derived Quantities
Optimization
chi-squared and the Likelihood Ratio Test
Proof of the Gauss-Markov Theorem
Rudimentary Graph Theory
Information Theory
Hypothesis Testing
Writing R Functions
Random Variable Generation
```

Comment: I point people to Cosma's notes regularly. There's some good material in there

Answer (score 8):

Some free Stats textbooks are also available [here](http://www.e-booksdirectory.com/mathematics.php).

Answer (score 8):

I know other authors have gone to some trouble to make their books available here on stack exchange ...  The printed version of our 2002 edition was printed 3 times and sold out 3 times;  Springer and Google recently started selling it (book only) as a PDF eBook (no software) on the Springer and Google sites for $79.

We are delighted to be able to make the PDF eBook version (2002 edition) available for FREE to stackexchange users at:

http://www.mathstatica.com/book/bookcontents.html

[image]

This is a complete PDF version of the original 2002 printed edition. Although no software is included (neither *Mathematica* nor *mathStatica*), the methods, theorems, summary tables, examples, exercises, theorems etc are all useful and relevant ... even as a reference text for people who do not even have *Mathematica*.

One can either download:

- the entire book as a single download file ... with live clickable Table of Contents etc,  ... or
- chapter by chapter.

**iBooks installation**

To install as an iBook:

- Download the entire book as a single PDF file
- Then drag it into iBooks (under the section: PDF files).

**iPad installation**

To install on an iPad:

- First install it as an iBook (as above)
- Open iTunes; select your iPad; click on Books: select the book and sync it over to your iPad.

Answer (score 8):

It's nice to see academics freely distribute their works. Here is trove of free ML / Stats books in PDF:

**Machine Learning**

- [**Elements of Statistical Learning** Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/%7Etibs/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print10.pdf)
- [**All of Statistics** Larry Wasserman](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/%7Ermjbale/Stat/wasserman2.pdf)
- [**Machine Learning and Bayesian Reasoning** David Barber](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/textbook/090310.pdf)
- [**Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning** Rasmussen and Williams](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf)
- [**Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms** David MacKay](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Emackay/itprnn/book.pdf)
- [**Introduction to Machine Learning** Smola and Vishwanathan](http://alex.smola.org/drafts/thebook.pdf)
- [**A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition** Devroye, Gyorfi, Lugosi](http://www.szit.bme.hu/%7Egyorfi/pbook.pdf)
- [**Introduction to Information Retrieval** Manning, Rhagavan, Shutze](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/irbookprint.pdf)
- [**Forecasting: principles and practice** Hyndman, Athanasopoulos (Online Book)](http://otexts.com/fpp/)

**Probability / Stats**

- [**Introduction to statistical thought** Lavine](https://www.math.umass.edu/%7Elavine/Book/book.pdf)
- [**Basic Probability Theory** Robert Ash](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/%7Er-ash/BPT/BPT.pdf)
- [**Introduction to probability** Grinstead and Snell](http://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Eprob/prob/prob.pdf)
- [**Principle of Uncertainty** Kadane](http://uncertainty.stat.cmu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/principles-of-uncertainty.pdf)

**Linear Algebra / Optimization**

- [**Linear Algebra, Theory, and Applications** Kuttler](https://math.byu.edu/%7Eklkuttle/Linearalgebra.pdf)
- [**Linear Algebra Done Wrong** Treil](http://www.math.brown.edu/%7Etreil/papers/LADW/LADW.pdf)
- [**Applied Numerical Computing** Vandenberghe](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/103/reader.pdf)
- [**Applied Numerical Linear Algebra** James Demmel](http://uqu.edu.sa/files2/tiny_mce/plugins/filemanager/files/4281667/hamdy/hamdy1/cgfvnv/hamdy2/h1/h2/h3/h4/h5/h6/Applied%20Numerical%20Linear%20.pdf)
- [**Convex Optimization** Boyd and Vandenberghe](http://www.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)

**Genetic Algorithm**

- [**A Field Guide to Genetic Programming** Poli, Langdon, McPhee](http://dces.essex.ac.uk/staff/rpoli/gp-field-guide/A_Field_Guide_to_Genetic_Programming.pdf)
- [**Evolved To Win** Sipper](http://www.lulu.com/ie/en/shop/moshe-sipper/evolved-to-win/ebook/product-18719826.html)
- [**Essentials of Metaheuristics** Luke](http://cs.gmu.edu/%7Esean/book/metaheuristics/Essentials.pdf)

Comment: If LADW is mentioned, perhaps LADR by Axler could have been mentioned too; the latter is way better book imo.

Answer (score 7):

Statsoft's [Electronic Statistics Handbook](http://www.statsoft.com/textbook/) ('The only Internet Resource about Statistics Recommended by Encyclopedia Britannica') is worth checking out.

Comment: This link now redirects to a product page for a data science/AI software. Can you update the link, if this resource is still freely available?

Answer (score 6):

Not properly an entire textbook, but the part IV of [Mathematics for Computer Science](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_notes.pdf) is about probability and random variables.

Answer (score 6):

Some downloadable notes on probability, which seems interesting:
http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math19b_2011/handouts/chapters1-19.pdf

Applied probability:
http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~bialas/EAS305/docs/EAS305%20NOTES%202005.pdf

http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~razk/Teaching/LectureNotes/LectureNotesProbability.pdf

Answer (score 5):

[A write up](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2012/08/understanding-bayesian-inference.html) of probability tutorials and related puzzles along with R code for learning. Hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

http://www.probabilitycourse.com/ is a website hosting free online-based Probability and Statistics textbook. It also has extra features such as graphing tools and lecture videos

Answer (score 5):

Here is also a great free book on multivariate statistics by Marden, primarily concerned with the normal linear model linked on this page:

[Multivariate Statistics Old School by John I. Marden](https://people.stat.sc.edu/hansont/stat730/Marden2013.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Gelman et al. ["Bayesian Data Analysis"](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/) (3rd edition).

[image]

Comment: How do I shrink the picture? :)

Comment: on the image file if you add some whitespace it will shrink and fit to width. Alternatively, you may use a lower resolution image.

Comment: Use [ImageMagick](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=imagemagick&atb=v235-1&ia=web). E.g., `convert xxx -density 600 -resize 25% xxx`.

Comment: @chl, thanks. I was looking for a built-in solution. Otherwise there are multiple services to choose from. I use FastStone Photo Resizer every now and then.

Comment: No built-in skrinking feature, AFAIK. +1, BTW, this was a very nice free update from the authors of this memorable textbook.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a textbook but [Bayesian Methods in the Search for the MH370](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-10-0379-0) is a great introduction to particle filters.

S. Davey, N. Gordon, I. Holland, M. Rutten, and J. Williams, Bayesian Methods in the Search for MH370 (2016)

Answer (score 1):

A **digital textbook** on probability and statistics by M. Taboga can be found at https://www.statlect.com The level is intermediate. It has hundreds of solved exercises and examples, as well as step-by-step proofs of all the results presented.

Answer (score 0):

For an introduction to the statistical analysis of networks, *[Statistical Analysis of Networks](https://nowpublishers.com/article/BookDetails/9781638280507)* by Konstantin Avrachenkov and Maximilien Dreveton. The paper version isn't free, but the [PDF version](https://nowpublishers.com/article/DownloadEBook/9781638280507?format=pdf) is. It is published under a Creative Commons By-NC licence.