# Open Source statistical textbooks?

Tags: references, open-source

There have been a few questions about statistical [textbooks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textbook), such as the question [Free statistical textbooks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/170/free-statistical-textbooks). However, I am looking for textbooks that are Open Source, for example, having an [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/) license. The reason is that in course material in other domains, you still want to include some text about basic statistics. In this case, it would be interesting to reuse existing material, instead of rewriting that material.

Therefore, what Open Source textbooks on statistics (and perhaps machine learning) are available?

Comment: On the other hand, can a book be open source? It rather applies to code, so probably the better word is "open book".

Comment: The site that is very close to open-source statistical handbook is http://stats.stackexchange.com :)

Answer (score 13):

Try IPSUR, *Introduction to Probability and Statistics Using R* by G. Jay Kerns. It's "free, in the GNU sense of the word".

http://ipsur.r-forge.r-project.org/book/

It's definitely open source - on the download page you can download the LaTeX source or the lyx source used to generate this.

Answer (score 12):

Michael Lavine: [*Introduction to Statistical Thought*](https://people.math.umass.edu/%7Elavine/Book/book.html), licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0 United States License.

Answer (score 10):

[Multivariate statistics with R](https://web.archive.org/web/20100831020331/http://www.opentextbook.org/2009/04/03/multivariate-statistics-with-r/)

Comment: Thi is a broken link

Comment: Does this refer to Paul Hewson's book [*Multivariate Statistics with R*](http://local.disia.unifi.it/rampichini/analisi_multivariata/Hewson_notes.pdf) (2009, 177 pages)?

Answer (score 7):

The ["Statistics"](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Statistics) book on wikibooks

Answer (score 6):

[OpenIntro Statistics](http://www.openintro.org/stat/textbook.php) is available via CC BY-SA. The LaTeX source code plus the R code to generate every figure in the textbook is also readily available in a single download.

OpenIntro's website also [highlights several other freely available statistics textbooks](http://www.openintro.org/stat/extras.php?feature=textbook_more_free_books)$^\dagger$ at the beginner, intermediate, and advanced levels.

---

$^\dagger$ not working anymore.

Answer (score 5):

*[Street-Fighting Mathematics](https://direct.mit.edu/books/oa-monograph/5339/Street-Fighting-MathematicsThe-Art-of-Educated). The Art of Educated Guessing and Opportunistic Problem Solving* by Sanjoy Mahajan from MIT. Available under a Creative Commons Noncommercial Share Alike license.

Available as a free download on the MIT Press website (but not from the [author's website](http://streetfightingmath.com/)).

Answer (score 5):

[Statistical Analysis with the General Linear Model](https://web.archive.org/web/20160130145908/https://www.psy.otago.ac.nz/miller/StatsBook.htm)

It covers basic linear models (ANOVA, ANCOVA, multiple regression). I can tell by personal experience that it is really really good book to get into the general framework of linear models, which are very useful in many advanced approaches (e.g., hierarchical modeling).

Comment: This is Creative Commons but does not allow derivates... :( That way, I cannot use the bits in my own course material, just the bits I need them to know...

Answer (score 4):

[R programming wiki book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming)

Answer (score 4):

Some googling found [Statistics & Probability on CollegeOpenTextbooks.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219010017/http://collegeopentextbooks.org/textbook-listings/textbooks-by-subject/statisticsandprobability). Still, be aware that most of CC-ed material is share-aliked (so you must also publish your work on CC) or at least attributed (so you must add info that certain part was copied and from whom). The same works with GFDL (both SA & A), it is even worse since in principle you should print it along with the document.

Answer (score 4):

[*Collaborative Statistics*](https://people.brandeis.edu/%7Efournier/col10522stats.pdf) is CC.

Answer (score 1):

Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning (by David Barber, Cambridge University Press) has an [online version which is freely available](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Brml.HomePage), but without any mention to a specific license. However, the [Instructors Material](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Brml.Instructors) page seems to imply that the exercises in the book can be used as teaching material, if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Look at Statistics Topics ebook on Amazon by Mehta, and his free web log Statistics Ideas that has lecture slides.  Nearly free and better in some pedagogical topics, than the ones you cite on your list of resources.

Comment: Does it have a creative commons license or something similar, like the question asked?