# References about the theory of linear regression or regression in general

Tags: regression, references

I am looking for references about the theory of linear regression or regression in general. More specifically, I am interested in knowing under what circumstances an estimated regressor is going to give accurate solutions with certain probabiltiy. For now, I am looking for the basic classical results, nothing too fancy or modern.

Answer (score 2):

A classic reference for the theory of general linear models is Searle: Linear Models

@article{searle1971linear,
  title={Linear models},
  author={Searle, SR},
  year={1971},
  publisher={Wiley Series in Probability and Mathematical Statistics}
}

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for basic statistics I recommend Khan Academy, they have an excellent series on the theory of [regression lines](http://www.khanacademy.org/video/squared-error-of-regression-line?playlist=Statistics). You can alson check out [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/170/free-statistical-textbooks) about free statistical textbooks.