# Online reference for review of introductory statistics material

Tags: references

Can anyone suggest a good **review** reference (necessarily free online PDF) to brush up college-level statistics?

I'm looking at something which typically covers a first course in statistics ideally covering:

- Absolute basics (mean, variance etc.)
- Large Samples
- Confidence testing
- Hypothesis testing (normal, t, chi, F)
- Linear Regression/Correlation

I don't need a book reference. I need something like a quick review which goes over the important aspects. Anything in free form will do : Presentations, Lecture Notes or otherwise. I just need it to be succinct; depth would be much appreciated.

Comment: Good links here: http://www.r-statistics.com/2009/10/free-statistics-e-books-for-download/

Comment: I especially liked [Introduction to Statistical Thought](http://www.math.umass.edu/~lavine/Book/book.html) by Michael Lavine

Comment: Note that "succinct" & "depth" are pretty much contradictory. You should clarify this; eg, if you found the ideal book, roughly how long would it be in pages? In addition, I'm guessing you want a review of introductory **applied** stats, not mathematical statistics.

Comment: @gung. Succinctness is primary, depth is appreciated. I'd prefer ~150 pages not more. Yeah, I think this would be applied although I'm not sure I understand the difference very well.

Comment: While this previous post focuses on free online textbooks, you may find a number of good resources: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/170/2981

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these documents:

http://onlinestatbook.com/Online_Statistics_Education.pdf

http://www.micquality.com/downloads/ref-primer.pdf

And at this site, for more materials:

http://onlinestatbook.com/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

These are not PDFs, but there are quite a few good videos at the [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics).

Answer (score 1):

There are so many good possibilities and your vague description makes it difficult to narrow it down to just a couple.
But here is a short list.
1.  Humourous but also clear and accurate by Gonick "The Cartoon Guide to Statistics 1993"
[http://www.amazon.com/Cartoon-Guide-Statistics-Larry-Gonick/dp/0062731025/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1341601837&sr=1-1&keywords=the+cartoon+guide+to+statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062731025)

1. Clearly written in the style of David Moore "The Basic Practice of Statistics 5th Edition 2010."
   [http://www.amazon.com/Basic-Practice-Statistics-David-Moore/dp/1429201215/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1341601954&sr=1-2&keywords=the+basic+practice+of+statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1429201215)
2. Good college level book by Hogg and Tanis "Probability and Statistical Inference 8th Edition 2009." Now Published by Prentice-Hall.  Was published by Macmillian when I studied out of it in the 1970s  The authors were Hogg and Craig then and the title was different too.  I had it as "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics 3rd Edition 1970."

[http://www.amazon.com/Probability-Statistical-Inference-Robert-Hogg/dp/0321584759/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1341601657&sr=1-1&keywords=hogg+tanis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321584759)

1. The classic by Mood, Graybill and Boes 1974 "Introduction to the Theory of Statistics".

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Theory-Statistics-3rd-Edition/dp/0070854653/ref=la_B002880BCE_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1341601600&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070854653)

1. Very modern first year undergraduate introductory text.  One of my favorites because it includes resampling methods.  Chihara and Hesterberg "Mathematical Statistics with Resampling and R, 2011" 
   [http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Statistics-Resampling-Laura-Chihara/dp/1118029852/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1341602206&sr=1-1&keywords=Chihara+and+Hesterberg](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118029852)
2. This is the only good one that is concise "pocketbook" size. Silvey's "Statistical Inference 1975"
   [http://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Inference-Monographs-Statistics-Probability/dp/0412138204/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1341602312&sr=1-1&keywords=silvey+s+d](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412138204)

Comment: (necessarily free Online PDF) ?

Comment: Sorry I read your note wrong.  I thought you said not necessarily free Online PDF.  Requiring a good review book in a free online PDF is a tall order.  Maybe that is why it was downvoted.  I think that the question is reasonable.  So I gave you an upvote.  Would a good powerpoint presentation do?  I can give you one that I produced and use for introductory biostatistics lectures?

Comment: Sure. I'll edit the question to make it more encompassing.

Comment: I will attach my slides if someone will explain to me how to do it.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: I don't think it's possible. But why don't you use one of the free file exchange services and link to it in the answer?

Comment: You could use any of the free services such as 4shared.com for hosting your file.

Comment: Okay but could somebody tell me the steps necessary to attach the file.  I know it is possible to do but I still don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think these two free PDF's are very good for this purpose:

This one is a more "conceptual" introduction, good for a refresher:

http://www.stat-help.com/intro.pdf

And this one is a more "complete" introduction:

http://www.openintro.org/stat/down/OpenIntroStatFirst.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The [NIST/SEMATECH e-Handbook of Statistical Methods](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/), also known as the Engineering Statistics Handbook is a great, and authoritative, reference. It is continuously supported by the National Institute of Standards and Technology (U.S. tax dollars at work!)

It is available in pdf at http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/toolaids/pff/index.htm

The organization is a bit unusual, but there is a good search function.

Answer (score 1):

David Colquhoun's book "Lectures on Biostatistics" covers most of the material that you mention and is available as a free pdf from the author's website http://www.dcscience.net/
It is slightly idiosyncratic in parts (which will not surprise any who know the author) and quite entertaining (the test for pureness of heart is wonderful). You can't go wrong.