# Most efficient way to check answers to exercises when learning from a statistics textbook?

Tags: self-study, references, checking

There's a community wiki at: [Free statistical textbooks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/170/free-statistical-textbooks/174#174) that has a nice list of freely available textbooks on statistics. Many of the textbooks that people suggest have exercises at the end of each chapter which is great, but very few of these textbooks have provided solutions to any of the exercises.  Sure there may be a variety of reasons for this, but if you are just going through these texts on your own, not in formal course where exercises sets usually have a grader, then that presents an issue as how are you supposed to check your answers.

Posting a new question on here to check to see if you got the right answer is not really practical I think.

Like that these resources are already free, but, and I'm sure others would agree, it's frustrating for a beginner.

e.g. How do i check my answers for @Rob Hyndman book: [Forecasting: principles and practice (Hyndman & Athanasopoulos, 2012)](http://otexts.com/fpp/)

List of solution manuals to books at [Free statistical textbooks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/170/free-statistical-textbooks/174#174):

1. [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) by Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman

   [A Solution Manual and Notes for: The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://waxworksmath.com/Authors/G_M/Hastie/hastie.html) by JL Weatherwax

Comment: So: how about you edit your post (the edit link is at the lower left) to ask an actual question (you originally put question marks at the end of declarative statements). This is a question and answer site: can you improve by asking an actual question in the body of your text?

Answer (score 3):

Statistical simulation works nicely, though it can take some time to implement. This skill will pay off in the long run, however.

Solutions manuals can often be found on-line. For instance, H & A have some solutions [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/resources).

Comment: +1 and I would also add that simulating solutions can be really useful practice for when one needs to use simulations for actual work

Comment: The link you provided requires proof that the person requesting solutions is an instructor.