# Is there any "Intro to Statistics" for business and mangement use?

Tags: references, decision-theory, business-intelligence

I am looking for an "Introduction to Statistics" to apply to business and management. Can someone recommend a source they have used (maybe in their MBA or similar studies) that is available online (and preferably free)?

I am looking for something that is readable for technical degree, and which does not assume any significant previous exposure to theory of statistics.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what extent of statistics you want covered by a book in question. The community on this page will probably have plenty of book recommendations about statistics as a whole, a lot of good recommendations have been gathered in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/170/free-statistical-textbooks). One of them, ['Elements of Statistical Learning'](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/), I can personally recommend.

If you want something with focus on applications in economy, you might want to have a look at the subfield of [econometrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Econometrics). 
Since the two books that were recommended to me by my PhD supervisor about this topic are sadly both in german and one of them only available as paperback, I cannot recommend one from personal experience. If you're searching for literature on the topic, books like [Introductory Econometrics](http://economics.ut.ac.ir/documents/3030266/14100645/Jeffrey_M._Wooldridge_Introductory_Econometrics_A_Modern_Approach__2012.pdf) will turn up that might suit your needs.