# Does rnorm produce numbers with replacement/without replacement?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, sampling, simulation, random-generation

[`rnorm`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/compositions/versions/1.40-3/topics/rnorm) is an R language function defined as:

```
rnorm.X generates multivariate normal random variates in the space X.
```

Consider `rnorm(1000, 50, 5)`, drawing 1000 values from a normal distribution with mean 50 and standard deviation 5.

Are these 1000 values iid? If they are then the sampling is done with replacement. Are `rnorm` and `runif` samples generated with replacement or without replacement?

Comment: That is not the [normal distribution](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html) in base R package stats.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Care to explain? rnorm is the way you draw random numbers from a normal distribution in base R.

Comment: @Ingolifs The link is to a function in a *contributed* package, that help page list 9 `rnorm.X`, functions, not `rnorm`, the base R function.

Answer (score 14):

Both the normal and uniform distributions are continuous; ie, any particular value has probability of zero. Obviously there is numerical precision and other considerations involved with a machine-specific implementation but for all intents and purposes, you can suppose that $\mathbb P(X = x) = 0$ for any particular $x$; ie, the probability that you randomly draw a value identical to any particular point you specify is $0$. Further, if you have any countable (ie, you could count it out, possibly infinite) or finite (ie, you have a set with a fixed number of elements) set $\mathcal X$, $\mathbb P(X \in \mathcal X) = 0$ as well. That is, for any countable set of real numbers within the support of the distribution (for the uniform case, this would be $[0, 1]$, and for the normal case, the support is just all of the reals) there is also a probability of $0$ that a "new draw" or any finite number of draws will be equal to any of them (this applies for *all* continuous distributions; one can define mixed distributions in which this is NOT the case, but for continuous random variables, this is *always* the case as by definition a continuous distribution is defined over uncountably infinitely many points). There is no such thing as "with replacement" and "without replacement" if the distn function is continuous; further, if the distribution is discrete "without replacement" explicitly violates $iid$ (as you are specifically and deliberately omitting values from the possible sets of values based completely on the values you have already obtained). `rnorm` and `runif` generate $iid$ samples.

Comment: “rnorm and runif generate iid
 samples” They are pseudo random number generators. They do *not* generate iid samples. See for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/465536/ that speaks about repetitions with runif that are more often than expected.

Answer (score 12):

For "with replacement" and "without replacement" to be distinct, you'd need a finite population. If you have a finite population, you don't have a normal distribution (nor any other continuous distribution).

[Implementation wise, however, there's only a finite number of different values that it's possible to generate on a computer -- at any fixed number of bits, the computer can only represent a finite number of different values, so in that sense you have a finite population, and strictly speaking the distribution is discrete rather than continuous. However the normal model is itself continuous even though we don't have a way to practically generate values that are truly/perfectly from it.]

Comment: As a minor add-on, there is a [X validated question on the practical & physical generation of Gaussian random variates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/247099/7224) that is ideally producing output with arbitrary precision.