# Statistical analysis of carbon dioxide flux data

Tags: anova, spss

I have been measuring flux of CO2 in (mmol m-2 d-1) from two different rivers and I now want to do a statistical analysis using IBM SPSS but I'm not sure where to start. One lake is showing negative flux, because the lake has acted like a sink for the CO2.

I have made a histogram first see how the data looks like, as you can see in the figure I’ve added additional data with label. As mentioned above, the negative values are from one lake and the positive values are from another lake

The labels show: what lake I have studied; what time I started the measurement and when I stopped measuring; the column daytime (1) describes when the sun is up and nighttime (2) describes when the sun is down; T_air oC and T_H2O describes describe the temperature in water and air during the measurement and FCO2 is a calculated variable of CO2 flux from its ppm to units of mmol m-2 d-1.

What I want to accomplish with the statistical analysis is first to understand how I should think before I start to analyzing;

- What leads to different values within each of the two lakes?
- What lead to different values between the two lakes?
  and
- What is the relationship between FCO2 and temperature?

Is there anyone who can come with some suggestion what statistically analysis I should use for each thing I want to accomplish? I have from somewhere I should use a one-way Anova but not sure where to start thinking.

Thank you for helping

[image: Histogram]

```
Lake & Initial sampling (date and time) & Final sampling (date and time) & Daytime (1) nighttime (2) & T\_air oC & T\_H2O oC & FCO2\_mmol m-2 d-1 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-16 18:35 & 2022-03-16 20:18 & 1 & 4.5   & 4.5   & -2.29507 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-16 20:33 & 2022-03-16 22:15 & 2 & 4.35  & 4.35  & -2.48989 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-16 22:35 & 2022-03-17 00:16 & 2 & 4.22  & 4.22  & -2.52834 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 00:35 & 2022-03-17 02:18 & 2 & 4.02  & 4.02  & -2.4524  \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 02:34 & 2022-03-17 04:13 & 2 & 4.12  & 4.12  & -2.47989 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 04:38 & 2022-03-17 06:15 & 1 & 4.36  & 4.36  & -2.18617 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 06:34 & 2022-03-17 08:16 & 1 & 5.35  & 5.35  & -1.86178 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 08:35 & 2022-03-17 10:17 & 1 & 6.07  & 6.07  & -2.42144 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 10:34 & 2022-03-17 12:18 & 1 & 7.44  & 7.44  & -2.52941 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 12:34 & 2022-03-17 14:17 & 1 & 8.16  & 8.16  & -2.21627 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 14:33 & 2022-03-17 16:19 & 1 & 7.97  & 7.97  & -2.55553 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 16:39 & 2022-03-17 18:17 & 1 & 7.52  & 7.52  & -2.0844  \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 18:34 & 2022-03-17 20:17 & 1 & 7.54  & 7.54  & -2.43122 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 20:34 & 2022-03-17 22:17 & 2 & 8.06  & 8.06  & -1.96291 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-17 22:35 & 2022-03-18 00:18 & 2 & 7.41  & 7.41  & -1.54653 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 00:38 & 2022-03-18 02:18 & 2 & 7.60  & 7.6   & -1.591   \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 02:35 & 2022-03-18 04:17 & 2 & 7.42  & 7.42  & -1.99879 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 04:36 & 2022-03-18 06:16 & 1 & 7.02  & 7.02  & -1.44514 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 06:35 & 2022-03-18 08:18 & 1 & 8.12  & 8.12  & -1.82221 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 08:33 & 2022-03-18 10:17 & 1 & 8.97  & 8.97  & -2.30534 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 10:34 & 2022-03-18 12:18 & 1 & 11.63 & 11.63 & -1.49893 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 12:37 & 2022-03-18 14:17 & 1 & 10.75 & 10.75 & -2.20711 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 14:38 & 2022-03-18 16:18 & 1 & 11.57 & 11.57 & -1.80309 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 16:41 & 2022-03-18 18:17 & 1 & 8.66  & 8.66  & -1.67234 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 18:37 & 2022-03-18 20:15 & 1 & 6.18  & 6.18  & -1.3983  \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 20:37 & 2022-03-18 22:17 & 2 & 5.02  & 5.02  & -1.32119 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-18 22:34 & 2022-03-19 00:17 & 2 & 4.50  & 4.5   & -1.45022 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 00:34 & 2022-03-19 02:17 & 2 & 4.74  & 4.74  & -1.49234 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 02:35 & 2022-03-19 04:18 & 2 & 4.75  & 4.75  & -1.16388 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 04:35 & 2022-03-19 06:18 & 1 & 4.34  & 4.34  & -0.87719 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 10:33 & 2022-03-19 12:17 & 1 & 13.33 & 13.33 & -1.04391 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 12:34 & 2022-03-19 14:18 & 1 & 11.86 & 11.86 & -1.15754 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 14:37 & 2022-03-19 16:18 & 1 & 14.32 & 14.32 & -1.3017  \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 16:35 & 2022-03-19 18:18 & 1 & 7.77  & 7.77  & -1.41987 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 18:33 & 2022-03-19 20:18 & 1 & 5.49  & 5.49  & -1.20405 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-19 20:35 & 2022-03-19 22:16 & 2 & 4.92  & 4.92  & -1.29523 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 08:34 & 2022-03-20 10:13 & 1 & 13.10 & 13.1  & -2.09114 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 10:34 & 2022-03-20 12:16 & 1 & 12.37 & 12.37 & -1.80007 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 12:32 & 2022-03-20 14:18 & 1 & 12.81 & 12.81 & -1.55716 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 14:34 & 2022-03-20 16:17 & 1 & 15.58 & 15.58 & -1.86034 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 16:34 & 2022-03-20 18:17 & 1 & 9.39  & 9.39  & -1.90103 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 18:33 & 2022-03-20 20:18 & 1 & 5.44  & 5.44  & -1.53041 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 20:35 & 2022-03-20 22:14 & 2 & 4.67  & 4.67  & -1.79374 \\
Victoria & 2022-03-20 22:37 & 2022-03-21 00:17 & 2 & 4.48  & 4.48  & -1.01154 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-29 21:55 & 2022-03-29 23:35 & 2 & 4.44  & 4.44  & 2.853022 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-29 23:56 & 2022-03-30 01:35 & 2 & 3.51  & 3.51  & 2.15667  \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 01:56 & 2022-03-30 03:34 & 2 & 2.38  & 2.38  & 2.231913 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 03:54 & 2022-03-30 05:35 & 2 & 2.16  & 2.16  & 1.759635 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 05:53 & 2022-03-30 07:35 & 1 & 3.7   & 3.7   & 1.001419 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 07:56 & 2022-03-30 09:35 & 1 & 7.8   & 7.8   & 0.960555 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 09:53 & 2022-03-30 11:35 & 1 & 9.98  & 9.98  & 1.991259 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 11:56 & 2022-03-30 13:34 & 1 & 10.25 & 10.25 & 1.517868 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 13:51 & 2022-03-30 15:34 & 1 & 10.2  & 10.2  & 1.821623 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 15:53 & 2022-03-30 17:35 & 1 & 9.63  & 9.63  & 1.741887 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 17:54 & 2022-03-30 19:35 & 1 & 6.38  & 6.38  & 2.141064 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 19:55 & 2022-03-30 21:35 & 2 & 4.96  & 4.96  & 2.685757 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 21:56 & 2022-03-30 23:35 & 2 & 4     & 4     & 2.923715 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-30 23:52 & 2022-03-31 01:11 & 2 & 3.54  & 3.54  & 3.316899 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-31 01:52 & 2022-03-31 03:34 & 2 & 2.99  & 2.99  & 1.681422 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-31 07:55 & 2022-03-31 09:35 & 1 & 10.4  & 10.4  & 1.361125 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-31 13:58 & 2022-03-31 15:34 & 1 & 12.34 & 12.34 & 0.734101 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-31 15:55 & 2022-03-31 17:35 & 1 & 8.69  & 8.69  & 0.947828 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-31 17:54 & 2022-03-31 19:35 & 1 & 6.6   & 6.6   & 0.512018 \\
Denveer  & 2022-03-31 19:53 & 2022-03-31 21:35 & 2 & 4.82  & 4.82  & 1.261292 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 06:04 & 2022-04-01 07:35 & 1 & 4.9   & 4.9   & 1.77807  \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 09:54 & 2022-04-01 11:34 & 1 & 7.73  & 7.73  & 1.738892 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 12:02 & 2022-04-01 13:22 & 1 & 9.9   & 9.9   & 1.109685 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 13:51 & 2022-04-01 15:35 & 1 & 9.06  & 9.06  & 1.232822 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 15:56 & 2022-04-01 17:36 & 1 & 8.57  & 8.57  & 0.857767 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 17:56 & 2022-04-01 19:34 & 1 & 4.62  & 4.62  & 1.44003  \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 19:53 & 2022-04-01 21:36 & 2 & 2.78  & 2.78  & 2.121573 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-01 22:04 & 2022-04-01 23:24 & 2 & 2.9   & 2.9   & 2.611131 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 00:01 & 2022-04-02 01:36 & 2 & 1.99  & 1.99  & 1.989111 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 01:56 & 2022-04-02 03:36 & 2 & 1.6   & 1.6   & 1.889324 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 03:56 & 2022-04-02 05:35 & 2 & 1.51  & 1.51  & 1.239421 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 05:54 & 2022-04-02 07:34 & 1 & 2.73  & 2.73  & 0.908215 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 07:58 & 2022-04-02 08:48 & 1 & 4.94  & 4.94  & 0.72762  \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 10:04 & 2022-04-02 11:26 & 1 & 11.35 & 11.35 & 0.634685 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 13:59 & 2022-04-02 15:37 & 1 & 9.45  & 9.45  & 0.851654 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 15:54 & 2022-04-02 17:38 & 1 & 8.7   & 8.7   & 1.322688 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 17:58 & 2022-04-02 19:38 & 1 & 6.64  & 6.64  & 1.169257 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 19:54 & 2022-04-02 21:39 & 2 & 5.25  & 5.25  & 1.483866 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-02 22:00 & 2022-04-02 23:40 & 2 & 4.87  & 4.87  & 1.363993 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 00:04 & 2022-04-03 01:36 & 2 & 4.78  & 4.78  & 1.777732 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 02:00 & 2022-04-03 03:40 & 2 & 4.8   & 4.8   & 1.488471 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 03:56 & 2022-04-03 05:40 & 2 & 4.54  & 4.54  & 0.842322 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 05:57 & 2022-04-03 07:41 & 1 & 5.12  & 5.12  & 1.25267  \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 07:58 & 2022-04-03 09:40 & 1 & 7.82  & 7.82  & 1.638629 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 10:02 & 2022-04-03 11:42 & 1 & 10.2  & 10.2  & 1.543532 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 11:59 & 2022-04-03 13:42 & 1 & 11.4  & 11.4  & 1.734148 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 14:02 & 2022-04-03 15:42 & 1 & 10.1  & 10.1  & 2.221091 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 16:01 & 2022-04-03 17:20 & 1 & 9.2   & 9.2   & 2.092675 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 19:59 & 2022-04-03 21:43 & 2 & 6.69  & 6.69  & 2.461853 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-03 22:03 & 2022-04-03 23:38 & 2 & 6.34  & 6.34  & 3.361063 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-04 00:01 & 2022-04-04 01:43 & 2 & 6.36  & 6.36  & 4.282346 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-04 02:02 & 2022-04-04 03:45 & 2 & 7.02  & 7.02  & 5.178646 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-04 04:08 & 2022-04-04 05:45 & 1 & 7     & 7     & 1.177135 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-04 06:08 & 2022-04-04 07:44 & 1 & 6.58  & 6.58  & 1.053295 \\
Denveer  & 2022-04-04 08:07 & 2022-04-04 09:24 & 1 & 6.74  & 6.74  & 1.20853
```

Comment: Could you explain how a gas measurement could be negative?  What parameter are you analyzing?  What is your second chart showing?  (Without labels or an explanation, it's essentially meaningless or possibly even confuses the matter.) Regardless, if all the values from one river are always less than values in the other river, you don't need to conduct a statistical test: the different is obvious.

Comment: Im sorry for late reply.

The negative gas measurement means that is has a negative flux. The river is acting like a sink for the gas.  The parameter that im looking at is ppm. A friend made the second chart for me and are using the same data as the one in the first Chart. 

I know its obvious as one is only having plus values and the other have minus values but, in my case it has to be proven statistically. 

I hope I made myself more clear for the help that im looking for

Comment: Without labels nothing is obvious about either chart. Your data listing seems to have date, time, depth, and C02. What role does each of these play in your proposed analysis. What is the relevance of depth? // To the extent that your question is restricted to specifics of particular software (Excel, SPSS), it may be off topic here. Please focus on why the study was done and what you hope to find out.

Comment: Thank you for reply, BruceET,

For the moment, column lake, FCO2 and Daytime (1) Nighttime (2) are the important.  
I added the whole table just so it was done. To answer your question about what the the relevance for depth is that I may want to check if there is a different between just the depth on the lake, where the monitor where places, of both places.

Comment: - First, I want to check the variability within each lake. I made this extra column ( daytime (1), nighttime (2)) in Excel before I imported them into SPSS as I thought it would make it easier to separate them. 
- The second thing I want to find out is the variability between each lake.

Comment: The last column is FCO2 calculated variable of CO2 from ppm to mmol m-2 d-1.

As mention above the negative data is from one lake and the positive data is from another lake

Comment: The purpose is to have the same temperatur in both and not whats important. And im aware that these have different date and one of the interpretation I will do later on. My focus and question here is on the statistical side and not the philosophical side. But thank you for your comment

Comment: @bruceET, would you say it more clear now?

Comment: It looks like your third question, "What is the relationship between FCO2 and temperature," can be studied with these data.  Start by looking at scatterplots of the (Temperature, FCO2) pairs, one for each lake.  What the relationship might be between this question and "variability between each lake" is not evident, though.  This isn't some extraneous matter of "philosophy:" it's crucial to understanding what you're trying to do and deciding what statistical procedures might be useful and make sense.

Comment: Thank you @whuber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you don't seem to have a lot of background in exploring data of this kind and ultimately modeling it with multiple regression, I'll walk you through some steps. I don't use SPSS so I'll illustrate with R. I suspect that this can be done similarly in SPSS.

You made a good start by looking at the histogram of `FCO2` values. Next, extend that to looking at a set of critical predictors and all their pairwise associations. Looking at all of your data together is a good way to proceed.

I took your data, removed the `\\` end-of-line markers and extra spaces, kept the "&" field separators, and read them into a data frame, the format that R uses. I changed the field/column names to shorter versions.

```
lakeData <- read.table("lakeData.txt",sep="&",header=TRUE)
names(lakeData) <- c("Lake","startTime","stopTime","DayNight","airTemp","waterTemp","FCO2")
```

Note that the air and water temperature values are all the same, so we only have to deal with one of them

```
all.equal(lakeData$airTemp,lakeData$waterTemp)
## [1] TRUE
```

Make sure that "Lake" is treated as a categorical variable. The first value in alphabetical order, "Denveer," will be the reference level. Put the date/time data into a useful internal format. Extract the actual hour:minute values from each with a tool from the [`hms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=hms) in R. As the `HM` values (expressed here in seconds) are really continuous around the clock, also express them as angles from 0 to $2 \pi$ to simplify later analysis.

```
lakeData$Lake <- factor(lakeData$Lake)
lakeData$startTime <- as.POSIXct(lakeData$startTime)
lakeData$stopTime <- as.POSIXct(lakeData$stopTime)
library(hms)
lakeData[,"HM"] <- as_hms(lakeData$stopTime)
lakeData[,"timeAngle"] <- 2 * pi * as.numeric(lakeData$HM)/(24*60*60)
```

*Histograms and pairwise associations*

Now, examine the pairwise associations of some critical variables. The following requires you to first define a couple of helper functions, adapted from the help page for the standard R `pairs()` function, shown at the end of this answer.

```
pairs(lakeData[,c(7,1,2,5,8)],diag.panel=panel.hist, lower.panel=panel.cor,cex.cor=2,cex=1)
```

[image: pairs plot of critical variables]

This is a type of "pairs plot." The plots along the diagonal are histograms of each of these 5 variables. The first is pretty much the histogram of `FCO2` values you showed. Note the break in `startTime` values: some are in early to mid March, others in late March into April. The `airTemp` values are distributed from below 2 to over 14 degrees C. The sampling times within each day, the "HM" values in seconds past midnight, are reasonably uniform.

Now look at the off-diagonal plots at the upper right. They show the pairwise associations among these 5 critical variables. The numbers in the corresponding positions at the lower left are the pairwise correlation coefficients.

Look at the `Lake:startTime` pair. All of the earlier `startTime` values were for "Victoria"; all the later ones for "Denveer." That means that you won't readily be able to distinguish a trend over calendar time from a difference associated with `Lake`. That's emphasized in the `FCO2:startTime` pair. There's a clear hint of an increase of `FCO2` with time in the earliest observations (those from Lake Victoria), at least. The `startTime:airTemp` pair also shows some association at least for the measurements at earlier values of `startTime`.

The `airTemp:HM` pair shows the diurnal variation of `airTemp` evaluated over all of the 99 observations. That's part of what you attempted to capture with your binary "daytime/nighttime" variable, but it's generally best to [keep continuous predictors continuous](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/28500). Based on the `Lake:airTemp` pair, it seems that typical `airTemp` values differ between the two Lakes.

*Stop and think*

Your attempt to distinguish between the two lakes is unfortunately confounded by the systematic difference in calendar dates of sampling. That's a fundamental problem with a study like this. One could argue from the `FCO2:startTime` plot that most of the difference in `FCO2` values is just due to the dates of the samples. A skeptical reviewer of your study will be sure to point that out, however you try to account for that confounding by statistical analysis.

*Multiple regression*

When there are several predictors affecting a continuous outcome of interest, multiple linear regression can be a useful approach, as another answer suggests. That tries to account for effects of all of the predictors at once, moving beyond pairwise associations. That is more difficult, however, when the predictors are correlated as they are in this study.

You have 99 observations. To avoid overfitting, you can typically consider about 1 predictor per 10-20 observations: about 6 predictors here. Here's an example incorporating major predictors.

The angular predictor of time of day is modeled with separate `sin` and `cos` terms to account for how it wraps around (at midnight in these data). It looked like the association of `FCO2` and `startTime` differed between the two Lakes, so there's an interaction term to allow for that possibility. This models the association of `FCO2` with `startTime` as linear within each `Lake`; you might do better if you use a non-linear regression spline for `startTime`. I also transformed the `startTime` values into days since the first sample, to simplify interpretation of some coefficients. You might make different choices, based on your understanding of the subject matter.

```
lakeData[,"sampleDay"] <- (lakeData$startTime - min(lakeData$startTime))/(60*60*24)
lm1 <- lm(FCO2 ~ Lake + sampleDay + Lake:sampleDay + airTemp + sin(timeAngle)+cos(timeAngle),data=lakeData)
summary(lm1)

## some lines omitted

## Coefficients:
##                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept)             1.012680   0.833337   1.215   0.2274
## LakeVictoria           -3.991721   0.858045  -4.652 1.10e-05
## sampleDay               0.003145   0.052393   0.060   0.9523
## airTemp                 0.099420   0.038228   2.601   0.0108
## sin(timeAngle)          0.284655   0.114615   2.484   0.0148
## cos(timeAngle)          0.692550   0.142666   4.854 4.92e-06
## LakeVictoria:sampleDay  0.215383   0.095978   2.244   0.0272
##
## 
## Residual standard error: 0.6356 on 92 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.896,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8892 
## F-statistic: 132.1 on 6 and 92 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

This model captures nearly 90% of the variance among your `FCO2` values, as shown by the "R-squared" values. The coefficients are the changes in `FCO2` per unit change in the corresponding predictor, with all other predictors assumed constant. Interpreting these coefficient values is tricky, however, particularly with the interaction term.

The coefficient for `LakeVictoria` is the *difference* in `FCO2` from  that for the reference `Lake`, "Denveer," with other predictors held constant at baseline values, for example with `sampleDay = 0`. Lake Victoria thus seems to have a lower `FCO2` than Lake Denveer.

Remember, however, that there was no overlap in `sampleDay` values between the two lakes--Denveer had no samples taken until `sampleDay = 13`, so there must be some caution interpreting that baseline difference. Playing with predictions from this model suggests that extrapolations for Lake Victoria out to the last `sampleDay` at Lake Denveer lead to *higher* predicted `FCO2` for Victoria than for Denveer at that date.

There is an evident increase of `FCO2` with `airTemp`, about 0.1 flux unit per degree. This is assumed to be the same for both Lakes, as there was no `Lake` interaction coefficient involving `airTemp`. Was that a reasonable assumption?

The `sin` and `cos` terms nicely picked up a diurnal variation in `FCO2`, but this acts to *counteract* the otherwise expected change of `FCO2` with `airTemp` during the day. In the pairs plot, note how much flatter the `FCO2` values are through the day (`FCO2:HM` plot), versus the strong diurnal variation of `airTemp`. So if higher current `airTemp` leads to higher `FCO2`, then a flat `FCO2`  through the day means there has to be some counterbalancing diurnal effect. Does that make sense biologically? Maybe current `airTemp` isn't what matters?

The `sampleDay` coefficient isn't so simple as it might seem, because `sampleDay` is involved in an interaction with `Lake`. In this case it's the change in `FCO2` per extra day of sampling date *for the reference level of* `Lake`, or Lake Denveer. For that `Lake`, there seems to be no influence of `sampleDay` on `FCO2` levels.

The `LakeVictoria:sampleDay` interaction coefficient is the *difference between Victoria and Denveer* (the reference value of `Lake`) in the association of `sampleDay` with `FCO2`. There thus does seem to be an increase of `FCO2` with later sampling date for Lake Victoria, unlike for Lake Denveer. You need to think about the underlying biogeochemistry to determine what might be going on here; I worry that there were some rapid seasonal changes during the early samples at Victoria that had stabilized by the time samples were taken at Denveer.

It's important to do quality control to see how well the model fit the data and the underlying assumptions. I did that with `plot(lm1)` as a start, not shown here. There seem to be 2 outlying data points, the 2 highest ones on your histogram, but otherwise the model seemed OK with even a reasonably normal distribution of the residuals, the differences between the observed values and those predicted by the model. Without knowledge of the subject matter it's hard to know whether those apparent outliers represent a technical measurement failure or a failure of the model.

The lack of overlap between sampling dates from the two lakes showed up (via `car::vif(lm1)`) as a very high "variance inflation factor" (VIF) for each of `Lake` (45) and `sampleDay` (34). The VIF is an estimate of how unreliable your coefficient values might be due to correlations among the predictors. Those values (well over the rule of thumb of 10 or so for a "high" VIF) emphasize the potential problem posed by this experimental design.

*Summary*

One could argue from the multiple regression results that all of those predictors play roles in determining `FCO2`. Although the result shows a highly "statistically significant" difference between Lakes Denveer and Victoria, the lack of overlap in sampling dates during what might be a change of season requires care in interpretation.

For planning future studies, it's a good idea to include the data analysis approach as part of the planning. Then you can see problems in the experimental design, like this lack of overlap between Lakes in sampling dates, and alter your experimental design accordingly.

To learn more about this type of data analysis, see suggestions for books on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/170/28500) and [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/421/28500), among others on this site. Frank Harrell's [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) and [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) on "Regression Modeling Strategies" are particularly helpful, although they might assume a bit more background in statistics than you currently have. Working with a local experienced colleague and statistician would be very helpful and could help you avoid a lot of blind alleys along your path to becoming a more experienced data analyst.

---

Code for helper functions:

```
panel.hist <- function(x, ...)
 {
     usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
     par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
     h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
     breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
     y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
     rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, col = "cyan", ...)
 }

panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits = 2, prefix = "", cex.cor, ...)
 {
     usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
     par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
     r <- abs(cor(x, y))
     txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
     txt <- paste0(prefix, txt)
     text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex.cor )
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge with me! This is more than I asked for and very helpful for me! I don't know how to thank you more than just say it to you. R is something I really want to learn, and as you say, not losing information that could be important for the resource.

The reason why I did not share more information, is because it is on the internet and I want to avoid sharing my location to a greater extent than I already do.

Again, thank you so much EdM! I hope I can return here if I meet more challenge

Answer (score 1):

to find out what causes the difference between the two lakes, you could use a regreesion analysis like a GLM or a Multiple Linear Regression (but check the prerequisits for the latter).
Therebey, you could model the flux in dependency of different environmental variables (e.g., temperature, but you could add other environmental variables if you measured some, too).

Greetings
Jan